# WordPress add roles capabilities edit user

Tags: wordpress, addition, edit

I want to add the capability of adding/eddeting/removing users to a new role.
However I can't find the right capabilities.

Any help please?

Current (from the WordPress Codex)

```
add_role('new-role', 'New Role', array(
'read' => true, // True allows that capability
'edit_posts' => false,
'delete_posts' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
));
```

I would like to add something like: `add_user`, `edit_user` and `remove_user`

M.

-EDIT--EDIT--EDIT--EDIT--EDIT--EDIT-

I have made some progress. 
This is what I have now:

```
add_role('new-role', 'New Role', array(
'read' => true, // True allows that capability
'edit_posts' => false,
'delete_posts' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
'edit_users'=> true,
'level_10'=> true,
'delete_users' => true,
'create_users' => true,
'list_users'=>true,
'remove_users' > true,
'add_users' => true,
'promote_users'=> true
```

));

I can now add users but I can't edit users. The "user" tab doesn't show.
There is a "add new user" button under the "profile" menu.

M.

-EDIT--EDIT--EDIT--EDIT--EDIT--EDIT-
Okay I fixed it.

I was allready using the 'Adminimize' plugin so I duplicated the "Administrator"-role and hide everything that I didn't need:

```
function cloneRole()
{
global $wp_roles;
if ( ! isset( $wp_roles ) )
    $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();

$adm = $wp_roles->get_role('administrator');
//Adding a 'new_role' with all admin caps
$wp_roles->add_role('new_role', 'My Custom Role', $adm->capabilities);
}
```

Comment: I know this is a bit old but the Woocommerce Shop Manager role has managed it somehow, I am going to did around and see if I can find out how/

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no ability within WordPress to set a role to be able to edit users. Reading through the WordPress source code, there is only the add and delete options for users but there are edit buttons for plugins, themes, posts, pages etc.

The actual code can be found here: [WordPress Capabilities Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L0)

The lines it shows the user related roles are around line 1273 to 1288.

Sorry to disappoint.

Comment: I know this is a bit old but the Woocommerce Shop Manager role has managed it somehow