# Wordpress how do I give a custom role the capability to edit users

Tags: wordpress, user-roles

This may be a repeat of [WordPress add roles capabilities edit user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751909/wordpress-add-roles-capabilities-edit-user) but that was 2014 and things may have moved on. I also note that the WooCommerce Shop Manager role has (hookable) user capabilities; see [Allow Woocommerce shop manager to assign a role when creating a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72306268/allow-woocommerce-shop-manager-to-assign-a-role-when-creating-a-user).

This is my code;

```
/** Add tutor role */

$capabilities = array(
  'read' => true,
  'delete_posts' => true,
  'delete_published_posts' => true,
  'edit_posts' => true,
  'edit_published_posts' => true,
  'publish_posts' => true,
  'read_lesson' => false,
  'edit_users'=> true,
  'create_users' => true,
  'view_users' => true,
  'list_users' => true,
);

add_role('tutor',__('Tutor','heartoflanguage'), $capabilities);
```

But it not only doesn't work but calling the edit users page directly /wordpress/wp-admin/users.php returns the error "Sorry, you are not allowed to list users."

I would like my Tutors to be able to create their students. Any ideas?